# Is it possible to override the hover effect on the angular material 15 formfield

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I want to add custom style in the angular material input component. Need to override the hover effect for the appearance outline form field.

Just want to remove the black border which is appearing while hovering. I tried to find out which class is causing this issue. Found that the text-field--outlined class in the form field component is causing this. But not able to override that. Please provide a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You might have troubles with angular View Encapsulation and how its working.

First, you should try to disable ViewEncapsulation in your component to check if the css you wrote is correct :

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // Disable view encapsulation
})
export class MyComponentComponent {
  // Component logic here
}
```

The problem is, all the css you wrote for this component will be applied to the whole application once your component is loaded.

The best way to override material styles is to write your css in the styles.scss file.

The following code should work :

```
.my-component-class{
  .mat-form-field {
      &.mat-form-field-outline {
  
        .mat-form-field-outline-start,
        .mat-form-field-outline-end {
          border-color: red; // Replace with your desired color
        }
  
        .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
          &:hover {
            border-color: transparent; // Remove the black border on hover
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Let me check whether its works or not.

Comment: Is this css selectors there in Angular material 15 ?

Comment: these selectors are available independently of the angular version